# React JSX: How to avoid multiple onClick handlers for multiple elements

Tags: reactjs, jsx

New to React, coming from JS/jQuery land. Feel I have the basics down, but after quite a bit of searching, can't find the answer to the following issue. In jQuery, I can bind the same event handler to multiple child elements thusly:

```
$("#someId p").on("click", someFunction);
```

In React JSX, I've only figured out how to do the following, which seriously violates DRY, and reminds me of code I was writing years ago:

```
<div id="someId">
   <p onClick={this.someFunction}>Foo</p>
   <p onClick={this.someFunction}>Bar</p>
   <p onClick={this.someFunction}>Baz</p>
</div>
```

There's gotta be a better way, yes?

Comment: Add the onclick to the parent element and let event propagation bubble up, in the handler then check the target of the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put these p tags in list and use map function to render them.

```
let items=['foo','bar','baz'];

<div id="someId">
     {items.map((a,index)=>{
         return (
              <p key={index} onClick={(event)=>this.someFunction(event,index)}>{a}</p>
         );
      })}
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, that's the way to go, thanks! I've been using map() to render API data, hadn't thought to use it for my own local strings/elements.